# Return subclass from generic abstract class java

Tags: java, generics

So, I have this abstract class that represents an Input type object -

```
public abstract class Input<E>
```

And I have two classes that extends it, one is ButtonInput and the other is TextInput. Both extend Input so it doesn't really matter. I'll use TextInput just to explain.
 This is the TextInput class defention:

```
public class TextInput extends Input<TextInput>
```

What I'm trying to do is to return *this* as E (TextInput in this case)-

```
public E setTextColor(Color color) {
        this.colorText = color;
        return (E)this;
    }
```

So, If I call for example:

```
new TextInput().setColor(Color.black)
```

It should return TextInput. It is working but, it shows the following warning -

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
>           return (E) this;
>     required: E
>     found:    Input
>     where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in class Input

In relation to the following line of code -

```
 return (E) this;
```

Does anybody knows how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need `<E extends Input>` for the method, E is already parametrised.

Comment: Also, what is ButtonInput?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've removed what you've said and now when I'm compiling lint gives me a warning of unchecked cast.
And ButtonInput is just another class the represents a graphic button

Comment: But ButtonInput isn't in the code you've shown us. Please construct a complete test-case.

Comment: shouldn't you return "Input" instead of "E" ? I suggest you to watch this video: https://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded , presentation here: https://14b1424d-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded/effective_java_reloaded.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crtZj81aXkWeqfH_3muGqzxgmQ1BCl24RSKIpP6qgjBJ3_tqK3cK3ds5VWaPntKFI9IB3kJZNKPuy50IWt8VKyNlteLDNUCO-tlzD__3CpyRNmviitP6QOODPJXMcta6Ot8uCsn-Wgjo9E6jozDDHNHG8cmV_f5iGrSr0abi02IpSlKUk427PfIkA8OBavN31EeMn-P4SDdM-jmNAxQdCLO_MNfxJtYwF8hkFylakOBmIglsI0DgfWRtXmw5TlVuvb2f2au&attredirects=0

Comment: @OliCharlesworth changed it. ButtonInput and TextInput gives the same error, there's no difference as related to the question.

Comment: @Yehonatan: Ok, but your code and description are confusing.  Like I said, create a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could paste into an IDE.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I can't really get the answer from that presentation, and changing it to Input throws an error.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the help, I've changed the code and errors, hope you'll understand it.

Comment: @Yehonatan Have you watched the video? also, can you please show the whole code that is relevant ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pattern I've used in the past to solve this type of issue in abstract builder patterns. It relies on an abstract `me()` method that is overridden to return a reference to the concrete object.

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
    protected abstract T me();

    public T baz() {
        return me();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    protected Bar me() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really smart, I'll try doing it

Comment: Solved my problem. It's a bit tricky but working just fine and removes the warnings . Thanks.